# Most Elegant Implementation of MATLAB's "vec" Function in NumPy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, vectorization

In MATLAB there is a function referred to as `vec` that takes a matrix and stacks the columns into a single vector. For example if we call the following matrix "X":

```
[1 2]
[3 4]
```

then `vec(X)` would return the vector:

```
[1]
[3]
[2]
[4]
```

There doesn't seem to be any direct implementation of this, and the "[NumPy for MATLAB users](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html)" doesn't have a direct equivalent.

So, if one is given a numpy array (representing the matrix), what would a very elegant line of NumPy be to reproduce this result? Just curious to see how concise / elegant this can be made. Thanks!

Comment: I've never heard of `vec` in Matlab. Maybe you mean [this on the MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9061-risk-and-asset-allocation/content/AMeucciRiskandAssetAllocationRoutines/Ch9_OptimEstimationRisk/C_RobustAllocation/SeDuMi_1_1/vec.m)? In any case, it seems to be just `X(:)` in Matlab for 2-D arrays (vectors and matrices).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the "Fortran" `order` option to e.g. [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> a.reshape((-1, 1), order="F")
array([[1],
       [3],
       [2],
       [4]])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after. Using flatten unfortunately puts the NumPy array into the transpose of what it should be, where using the Fortran ordering seems to preserve this. Nice answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want is [`flatten()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

EG:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

>>> a.flatten('F')
>>> array([1, 3, 2, 4])
```

Thanks @jonrsharpe, I actually just looked it up too! BTW: transpose the array using `a.T.flatten()` is an alternate to changing the order using `order='F'`

Comment: Thanks Mark, this answer is also very nice as it is quite concise.

Comment: Vincent Russo - yes `flatten()` returns a column and not a row, because by default NumPy uses row-order and MATLAB uses column-order, which is an important distinction when learning NumPy after using MATLAB. Consequently, if you want to mimic MATLAB's column-order arrays you will end up using `reshape()` a lot, but you could get exactly the same results with simpler (IMHO more Pythonic) code if you transpose your paradigm to row-order. ;-)

Comment: A very good thing to note, thanks for pointing that out Mark, that's a great point. Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

For a 1-dimensional result, use [`X.T.ravel()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) or `X.T.flatten()`.  For a 2-dimensional column, use `X.T.reshape(-1,1)`.

Comment: +1 for use of `flatten()` as it is the most similar to MATLAB's linear indexing EG: `a(:)`, but I think that @jonrsharpe use of `order='F'` is better than transpose because it explicitly changes from NumPy's _row-order_ to MATLAB's (and Fortran's) _column-order_, which is a fundamental difference in MATLAB and NumPy which new users should understand